# Could not install package 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 2.1.0' in Xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, nuget, signalr

That's a weird one. I'm trying to install SignalR in this Xamarin project I'm working on, but the NuGet route is giving me this error:

`Could not install package 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 2.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1', 
but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework`

Further down the rabbit hole, I tried to install Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 2.1.0 by itself, which resulted in a slightly different error:

`Could not install package 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 2.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any...`

I find this very intriguing as I'm using VS2017 and .NET 4.5, which one would believe should work with the more recent libraries both from MS and from the community, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

I've looked around and there only a handful of sources talking about similar problems, however those are vastly outdated and usually gravitate around the fact that people were trying to get libraries built for the 4.5 framework to work with the 4.0 framework. Not me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, `targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81"` is what gave it away. Since the problem wasn't SignalR itself but rather Owin, I supposed I wouldn't really need Owin in my **client** aplication, only server-side, so I just installed the client package for SignalR:

```
PM> install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client
```

And that did it. There doesn't seem to be a compilation of Owin targeting the portable frameworks, at least that's what I figure. By installing only the client module, I skip the Owin dependence.